# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8 requested, with a size of 8

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i am getting the following problem any help will be very helpful (I always upvote) :

for some reason my code is logging what i believe should be done in two sets is done in six sets plus giving me an error.

here is my code :

```
  package com.nxstudio.suratbus;

    import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by rahul on 7/5/2016.
 */
public class DBHelper {

public void insert_coordinates(Context context){

    try {

        SQLiteDatabase eventsDB = context.openOrCreateDatabase("Coordinates", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        eventsDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coordinates (latitude VARCHAR,longitude VARCHAR,station VARCHAR)");

        eventsDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO coordinates (latitude, longitude ,station) VALUES ('1', '1','Station1')");

        eventsDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO coordinates (latitude, longitude ,station) VALUES ('2', '2','Station2')");

        Cursor c = eventsDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM coordinates", null);

        int latIndex = c.getColumnIndex("latitude");
        int longIndex = c.getColumnIndex("longitude");
        int stationIndex = c.getColumnIndex("station");

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()){

        while (c != null) {

            Log.i("lat", c.getString(latIndex));
            Log.i("long", Integer.toString(c.getInt(longIndex)));
            Log.i("Station", Integer.toString(c.getInt(stationIndex)));

            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }


    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }



}




}
```

here is my log :

```
    07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/lat: 1
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/long: 1
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/Station: 0
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/lat: 2
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/long: 2
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/Station: 0
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/lat: 1
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/long: 1
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/Station: 0
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/lat: 2
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/long: 2
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/Station: 0
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/lat: 1
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/long: 1
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/Station: 0
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/lat: 2
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/long: 2
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/Station: 0
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/lat: 1
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/long: 1
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/Station: 0
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/lat: 2
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/long: 2
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus I/Station: 0
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8 requested, with a size of 8
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:432)
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at com.nxstudio.suratbus.DBHelper$override.insert_coordinates(DBHelper.java:35)
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at com.nxstudio.suratbus.DBHelper$override.access$dispatch(DBHelper.java)
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at com.nxstudio.suratbus.DBHelper.insert_coordinates(DBHelper.java:0)
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at com.nxstudio.suratbus.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:75)
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5245)
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3740)
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-05 14:38:05.512 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
07-05 14:38:05.522 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 14:38:05.522 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-05 14:38:05.522 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-05 14:38:05.522 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
07-05 14:38:05.522 20886-20886/com.nxstudio.suratbus W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the crash, replace

```
while (c != null) {
    //...
    c.moveToNext();
}
```

with e.g.

```
do {
     //...
} while (c.moveToNext());
```

so that your loop terminates when there are no more results.

For the "two sets is done in six sets" issue, you can add `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS coordinates` before the `CREATE TABLE` to remove the old table with older data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while (c.moveToNext();) {
        Log.i("lat", c.getString(latIndex));
        Log.i("long", Integer.toString(c.getInt(longIndex)));
        Log.i("Station", Integer.toString(c.getInt(
    }
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToNext()

This will prevent the cursor from going over the last entry

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor don't have index 8 so you get `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`
So you should check if the cursor contains this index before get value from this index

```
 do {
     if (mCursor.getCount() > latIndex && mCursor.getCount() > longIndex && mCursor.getCount() > stationIndex) {
         Log.i("lat", c.getString(latIndex));
         Log.i("long", Integer.toString(c.getInt(longIndex)));
         Log.i("Station", Integer.toString(c.getInt(stationIndex)));
     }
 } while (c.moveToNext());
```

Comment: You're mixing up row and column indexing, and the loop never terminates.

Comment: Hey Phan Văn Linh thanks for trying , I appreciate it